# SendKey with special char @ (at-char)

Tags: powershell, sendkeys

I'm currently dealing with `SendKeys` and special chars, more specifically with the `@` (at-char).

```
$keys = "user@server"
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($keys)
```

This returns in fact just

```
userserver
```

The `@` is completely ignored.
I tried:

```
user(@)server
user{@}server
user`@server
```

But nothing worked...

I even tried to use a key combination to reach it, but since I need the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> (which is not mapped in the standard keys), I have to use something like this one on my keyboard: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>

So I tried then this:

```
^%2
^{%2}
^{%{2}}
```

But same results (this combination seems to be ignored or even fails with an error).

Any idea please?

EDIT:
I tried also this:

```
$keys = [System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode("user@server")
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait($keys)
```

But same results...

Comment: Hi, This works fine when I tried it in Powershell. I ran it in my ISE, what version of Powershell are you running? It worked on 5.1

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'd say PS version 5.1, right ?
`C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      16299  967`

Comment: That's the one. Weird. I literally copied your code and pasted it, and it sent the keys fine. I'll check again, and post back

Comment: From the docs: "The SendKeys class is susceptible to timing issues, which some developers have had to work around." - see the second note at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.sendwait?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_SendKeys_SendWait_System_String_. `@` does _not_ require escaping.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all of you...
I still have the same issue, as well with other similar chars (#,$...). I don't think it's a timing issue as the '@' in the middle of a string is just not displayed although the start/end of that string is.